# Display of API results with forEach in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to display data from an api and cant get a hold of using the forEach method correctly to show all the data at the same time. The API is working correctly. Here's the code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Text, View, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import axios from '../../utils/axios'
//import CurrencyPair from '../../CurrencyPair'
function HomeScreen() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true)

   
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchpairs = async() => {
            const result = await axios.get('/v3/accounts/{AccountId}/pricing?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_CAD')
            console.log(result.data)
            setData(result.data)
            setIsloading(false)
            
        }
        fetchpairs()
    }, [])

    
if(isLoading) {
    return (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
    )
}
else
return (
    <ScrollView>
        {[data].map((data) => (
            data.forEach(data =>{
           <Text>{JSON.stringify(data.prices[0].instrument)}
            {JSON.stringify(data.prices[0].closeoutAsk)}
            {JSON.stringify(data.prices[0].closeoutBid)}
            
            </Text>
            })
))}
    </ScrollView>
)
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: What does your `data` object look like?

Comment: The `data` is: `prices: Array(2) 0: asks: Array(1) 0: {price: "1.19061", liquidity: 10000000} length: 1 __proto__: Array(0) bids: Array(1) 0: {price: "1.19032", liquidity: 10000000} length: 1 __proto__: Array(0) closeoutAsk: "1.19061" closeoutBid: "1.19032" instrument: "EUR_USD" 1: asks: Array(1) 0: {price: "1.31015", liquidity: 10000000} length: 1 __proto__: Array(0) bids: Array(1) 0: {price: "1.30949", liquidity: 10000000} length: 1 __proto__: Array(0) closeoutAsk: "1.31015" closeoutBid: "1.30949" instrument: "USD_CAD" `

Comment: The Array.prototype.forEach function returns undefined, so your inner loop would need to use map instead if you want to return the <Text> elements. Note that you need to use the "return" symbol in front of the <Text> component call  when you use brackets for the anonymous function.

The above data printout is hard to read, any chance you could supply it in plain JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

Map is already taking care of forEach function

```
<ScrollView>
        {[data].map((item,i) => {
           
         return(<Text key={i}>{JSON.stringify(item.prices[0].instrument)}
            {JSON.stringify(item.prices[0].closeoutAsk)}
            {JSON.stringify(item.prices[0].closeoutBid)}
            
            </Text>
            )}
   )}
    </ScrollView>
```